# Add multiple tags to multiple posts

Tags: posts, tags, array

I have an array of posts IDs like this: `$id_post_array_full=array(239,243,246,248,250,252,255,257)` I would like to add tags for each posts with this function of wordpress `wp_set_post_tags()`.

My real problem is that I have multiple arrays of tags and for each of them  I have to match with the array of posts IDs

In the first red column I have the IDs and in the second red column I have the tags that I have to add for each one.

**I was thinking about that: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpzJi.png)**

Thanks for your time

Comment: What have you tried thus far? A couple PHP loops should make quick work of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

My array of IDs + tags is like this:

```
$array_tags_and_ids = [
'239' => ["car", "animal", "dog", "cat"],
'243' => ["dsa", "ewr", "bvc", "fgn"]
];
```

So I do:

```
 foreach ($array_tags_and_ids as $key => $value) {
         // re-call the value and get only the text value
         $implode_tags_names = implode( ', ', $value );

         // wordpress function
         wp_set_post_tags( $key, $implode_tags_names, true );

     }
```

Done

Comment: The implode step is unnecessary, you can pass the array directly (internally a comma-separated list is just turned into an array anyway).